# Как занести и вытащить данные с базы данных sqlite3

Tags: python, telegram, sqlite3

```
import sqlite3
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])

def subscribe(message: Message):

connect = sqlite3.connect('users6.db')

cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
last_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)""")

connect.commit()

people_id = message.chat.id
user1_name = message.chat.first_name
last_name = message.chat.last_name
cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = '{people_id}'")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_name FROM login_id WHERE user_name = '{user1_name}' ")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT last_name FROM login_id WHERE last_name = '{last_name}' ")
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    users_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    last_name1 = message.chat.last_name
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?, ?, ?);", (users_id, f'{first_name}', f'{last_name1}'))
    connect.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты подписался_ась на рассылку✅')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты уже подписан')
```

**Есть вот такая база данных и нужно чтобы в базу данных записывался город пользователя и нужно чтоб это сохранилось в базу данных, чтобы пользователь не вводил каждый раз город а при нажатие одной кнопки ему сразу показалось погода, еще добавил код ниже.**

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

def get_weather(message):

code_to_smail = {
    "Clear": 'Ясно\U00002600',
    "Clouds": 'Облачно\U00002601',
    "Rain": 'Дождь\U0001F327',
    "Thunderstorm": 'Гроза\U000026C8',
    "Mist": 'Туман\U0001F32B',
    "Snow": 'Снег\U00002744',
}

city = message.text.strip().lower()
res = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&units=metric&lang=ru&appid={API}')

with open(log_path, "a") as f:
    f.write("сообщение старт")
if res.status_code == 200:
    with open(log_path, "a") as f:
        f.write(str(res))
    data = json.loads(res.text)
    with open(log_path, "a") as f:
        f.write(str(data))
    temp = data["main"]["temp"]

    weather_description = data['weather'][0]['main']
    if weather_description in code_to_smail:
        wd = code_to_smail[weather_description]
    else:
        wd = 'Не могу распознать что там, посмотри сам'

    feels_like = data["main"]["feels_like"]
    pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
    humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
    wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'· На улице:  {wd}\n'
                     f'· Температура:   {int(temp)}°C\U0001f321\n'
                     f'· Но по ощущениям  {int(feels_like)}°C\n'
                     f'· Давление:  {pressure} мм.рт.ст\n'
                     f'· Ветер:  {wind} м/с\n'
                     f'· Влажность:  {humidity} %\n'
                     f'<b>Всего доброго!\n</b>', parse_mode='html',)
```

Comment: А что не получается? city = message.text.strip().lower() тут ты получаешь город, ну и записывай его в бд. А потом проверяй: если есть в бд - забирай оттуда, если нет - запрашивай у пользователя

Comment: Зачем три вызова `cursor.execute(f"SELECT` при наличии всего одного `cursor.fetchone()`?

Comment: При выполнении `INSERT` грамотно использована подстановка параметров. Почему тогда при выполнении `SELECT` используется интерполяция?

Comment: Я забрал информацию, а как проверять что она есть? И по одной кнопке выводить погоду?